# eslint disable extends in override

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

In the case where you have an override where you want to "downgrade" the js parser, how do you turn off the `extends` from the parent? `parserOptions` is easy to override because it is key-based. `extends` as an empty array does nothing, as it tries to append an empty list to the original. If you set it to `null`, you get a config parser error.

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['vendor/**/*.js'],
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 5,
        sourceType: 'script'
      },
      extends: [] // I want 'eslint:recommended' removed.
    }
  ]
};
```

The workaround involves looping over any extended rulesets and turning them all off.

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['vendor/**/*.js'],
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 5,
        sourceType: 'script'
      },
      rules: Object.keys(require(path.resolve(path.dirname(require.resolve('eslint')), '../conf/eslint-recommended')).rules).reduce((rules, rule) => {
        rules[rule] = 0;
        return rules;
      }, {})
    }
  ]
};
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are two ways to accomplish this:

1. **Separate files:**
   You can place a different `.eslintrc.js` file inside `vendor/` with `root: true`. That will ignore the `.eslintrc.js` at your project root.
2. **Separate overrides:**

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.js'],
      excludedFiles: 'vendor/**/*.js',
      // OR
      // files: ['src/**/*.js']
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: 'module',
      },
      extends: ['eslint:recommended'],
    },
    {
      files: ['vendor/**/*.js'],
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 5,
        sourceType: 'script',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```