# Are overrides plugins merged with non-overriding plugins in eslint?

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

I have an eslintrc file that looks similar to the following:

```
{
  plugins: ['flowtype'],
  // ...
  overrides: [{
    files: ['**/*.tsx', '**/*.ts'],
    plugins: []
  }]
}
```

When I lint a .tsx file, I am still getting flowtype lint errors. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: After reading this post, I believe the effect is the same as for the `extends` property: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107800/eslint-disable-extends-in-override